# Title above a table in Latex

Tags: latex

How can I have titles as in this example :

[image]

Here is my current code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\ding{233} EPU-N5-IED
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{15cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Cours 1: Informatique générale}\\
\hline
\PointingHand\textbf{ Heures}: CM : 20h, TD : 0h, TP : 160h\\
\PointingHand\textbf{ Objectifs}: L'objectif de [..] programmes informatiques.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And I have this when I compile :

[image]

Comment: Generally, Stack Overflow is for programming questions. LaTeX questions are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and are more suited for the [TeX/LaTeX Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To avoid the extra vertical spacing between your title and the table, avoid the `center` environment. You could use `\centering` instead, but as your table already fills more then the available width, I would rather make it just as wide as the textwidth
- to avoid the indention of your title, you can use `\noindent`
- have a look at the `xcolor` package to add the colour

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


{
\noindent\ding{233} \textcolor{green!50!brown}{EPU-N5-IED}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|p{.96\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{Cours 1: Informatique générale}\\
\hline
\PointingHand\textbf{ Heures}: CM : 20h, TD : 0h, TP : 160h\\
\PointingHand\textbf{ Objectifs}: L'objectif de [..] programmes informatiques.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I really appreciate it. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Taakk You're welcome!